# jquery twitter bootstrap IPad virtual keyobard

Tags: jquery, ipad, keyboard, virtual

I wanted to add a Ipad virtual keyboard to my page and it is shown as in image attached.

[image]

The main problem is that when textbox / text area gets focused, ipad keyboard should not popup and the user can only enter from virtual keyboard only.

Is there any jquery/ twitter bootstrap Plugin that solves my problem.

I have googled a lot but couldn't find the one I wanted.

Thanks

Comment: Do you realy need a textbox? If it's a homegrown keyboard you could use a div as a textarea and pop up your keyboard on klick in that div.

Comment: Div could also be used, but I need the virtual keyboard as shown in image displayed prehand.